# PCL - Kinect - No devices connected

Tags: kinect, opensuse, point-cloud-library

I am using Opensuse 12.3 (it causes some pain, but not my choice) and I want to use PCL to interface with the kinect and process the data.

I installed [freenect](http://software.opensuse.org/package/libfreenect), [openni](http://software.opensuse.org/package/openni) and [pcl](http://software.opensuse.org/package/pcl), and I can successfully run some freenect samples, like

- freenect-glview
- freenect-regview
- freenect-glpclview
- freenect-cvdemo
- freenect-cppview

If I

```
 lsusb
```

I get among others:

```
 Bus 001 Device 011: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
 Bus 001 Device 010: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
 Bus 001 Device 012: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

When I try to follow a simple [IO tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber) though, or run some precomipled samples, like

```
 pcl_openni_grabber_example
```

I get the error message

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pcl::PCLIOException'
   what():  No devices connected.
```

Any idea as what might be wrong?

There is a file "/etc/udev/rules.d/51-kinect.rules" with content

```
 # ATTR{product}=="Xbox NUI Motor"
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="045e", ATTR{idProduct}=="02b0", MODE="0666"

 # ATTR{product}=="Xbox NUI Audio"
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="045e", ATTR{idProduct}=="02ad", MODE="0666"

 # ATTR{product}=="Xbox NUI Camera"
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="045e", ATTR{idProduct}=="02ae", MODE="0666"
```

It's not exactly like suggested in [this page](http://www.david-montero.es/openkinect-in-opensuse/)
(configures the Kinect so it can be used as a normal user), and at work I don't have sudo/write rights to edit it myself (add e.g. GROUP="video") and test it, so that has to wait.

I cannot do either, what suggested [here](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Official_packages):

```
 sudo adduser $USER video
```

Could it be missing permissions/rights, that give no access to the kinect?

PS - there is no problem running no-kinect-related pcl things, like

```
 pcl_pcd_viewer /home/test_pcd.pcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this documentation: [pcl documentation page](http://pointclouds.org/news/2013/05/13/kinect-for-windows-with-pcl/) ?

You could also try it with the ROS system. It's is really easy to use with the *openni_launch* package ([take a look here](http://answers.ros.org/question/76033/openni_launch-with-standalone-pcl/))

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The installation was missing ps-engine and I wasn't able to find a ppa for that specific library.

However, I was able to get it to work by downloading and installing the driver here : https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/downloads

Ref: http://www.pcl-users.org/Can-t-use-Kinect-in-Ubuntu14-04-td4033666.html

If that doesn't work, you can also try the solution given here: http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_troubleshooting#Microsoft_Kinect